# Bootstrap grid system: How to change width for specific elements only?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, grid

How can I change the bootsrap grd's width for specific elements only without effecting the [default customisation](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/)?

Here is the screen grab for what I mean,

[image]

For instance, I want to change `col-xs-1` **smaller** like the the top row (the row with an add button)

```
<div class="col col-xs-1">
    <input type="checkbox" name="delete[]" />
</div>

<div class="col col-xs-11">
...
</div>
```

is it possible?

Comment: Change the grid system to 24 grids instead of 12. You can create smaller grids like that

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way is use [auto-layout](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#auto-layout-columns) colum on the left...

```
<div class="col-md-auto">
 <input type="checkbox" name="delete[]" />
</div>
<div class="col col-xs-11">
 ...
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Bootstrap 4 you need to add custom CSS like

```
<div class="col col-xs-1 col-xs-1point5">
  <input type="checkbox" name="delete[]" />
</div>

<div class="col col-xs-11 col-xs-10point5">
  ...
</div>
```

Adding css :-

```
.col-xs-1point5 {
  -ms-flex: 0 0 10%;
  flex: 0 0 10%;
  max-width: 10%;
}
```

The above css values are not exact but you can change those to your custom width & make sure all the % values are same.

Answer (score -1):

Please add a class on     `<div class="col col-xs-1">` and tell your width on that class in css

```
<div class="col col-xs-1 small_width">
        <input type="checkbox" name="delete[]" />
    </div>

    <div class="col col-xs-11">
    ...
    </div>
<style>
.small_width{
  width:30px;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this..

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-2">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-1"><input type="checkbox" name="delete[]"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-1">
          <button class="btn btn-default">Text</button>
        </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

You may also find this 24 column grid example useful..

http://www.bootply.com/113382

Answer (score -1):

If you are using checkbox, no need to add `col` Correct format below.

```
<div class="checkbox">
 <input type="checkbox" value="">
 <button type="submit">Sign in</button>
</div>
```

Source : http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-controls

See Checkbox section.